# android verify paypal payment

Tags: android, paypal

I am integrate paypal in android app.
payment is fine,via mobile sdk.
But verify have problem.
1) is verify have to use classic API?
2) when I use Adaptive Payments to verify, according https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

There is a sdk_cert.p12 file setting on the sdk-config.properies, acct3.CertPath=resource/sdk-cert.p12

Now I always get error.
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyManagerFactory SunX509 implementation not found
QUESTION:
1) I am using android, how could I set the right certpath??
2) could I not use this certpath??

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff here from the PayPal Mobile SDK team.

1) Yes, for the time being, you'll need to use the classic Adaptive Payments API to verify PayPal transactions.

2) This error is because the version of Java in Android is not compatible with the PayPal Java SDK.  The Java SDK was built for server side transactions.  In fact, you should NOT be verifying transactions on the device at all, but rather should be verifying the transaction on your own server (server-to-server calls).  You can use any language you want to make the server-to-server calls, as long as you verify the payment is valid on your own servers before shipping goods or rendering services.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I search a lot, all answer point to server side validation. Thx.

Comment: Hi Jeff, now as paypal has its new sdk for android!.is it possible to verify payment through android side or still i have to use server-to-server call?

Comment: No, it is recommended to [verify](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) server-to-server.  This is so you know for certain that the payment completed from a trusted source, and so you don't have to embed any sensitive credentials in your app.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks. server-to-server call do works for adaptive api and i get response. but when i tried it for Rest api (For Credit card) curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/ i get no response

Comment: Jeff, I'm building an iOS app that's using PP for payments.  It all works fine.  However when my server gets the payment id (pay_key or payment_id) I get a no payment found response.  I'm using the ruby gems for PP.

Comment: ..Continued:  Jeff, can you verify the best practice for payment verification.  is the server-to-server as I'm doing the recommended approach or is their an IPN setting now?  Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest continuing to use server-to-server validation.  You could play around with IPNs to see if it has the info you need, but it's highly unlikely.  Also, if you have new questions, let's create a new SO post, as the scope of this question has grown a bit unwieldy.

Comment: Started a new post with my original issue and tried to ask the question a little more clearly.  Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408731/paypal-server-to-server-verification-issue

Comment: Sent a bug report to PayPal, after they verified the issue it was fixed right away!