# PayPal Server-to-Server verification issue

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm building an iOS app that's using PP for payments. It all works fine.   The app gets an approved transaction from PP.  The app then sends the approved id (pay_key or payment_id) to our server for verification.  When the server receives the payment id, the verification call ( for creditcards “Payment.find(id)” to find the payment) returns a “no payment found” response.  The adaptive call for PP payments responses the same.

Basically, both calls can not find the payment approved by the app.

I'm using the ruby gems for PP adaptive and rest.

Also,  Jeff Brateman from the PP Android team answered the following server-to-server best practice question, but I would like to know, what is the best practice moving forward.  Will the server-to-server approach I’m using now be the best practice over the next year? Is is IPN going to be the way to go?

Original Best practice question and answer from Jeff:
[android verify paypal payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623950/android-verify-paypal-payment)
[Question from Rick] Jeff, can you verify the best practice for payment verification. is the server-to-server as I'm doing the recommended approach or is their an IPN setting now?

[Response from Jeff] I would suggest continuing to use server-to-server validation. You could play around with IPNs to see if it has the info you need, but it's highly unlikely. Also, if you have new questions, let's create a new SO post, as the scope of this question has grown a bit unwieldy.

Comment: UPDATE:

Bug definition:

All payment attempts work from the iOS SDK, creditcard and PayPal.  However, for credit card payments, if the "Save creditcard" option is set, the first payment will validate on the server-to-server call.  The next payment using the saved creditcard information will always fail.  Additionally, all PayPal (none Creditcard) payments fail the server-to-server call, but succeed on the PayPal iOS SDK.

This happens in the PayPal sandbox on the iOS simulator (iOS 6/7) and on a real device (iOS 6/7).  

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I sent a bug report to PayPal support, they verified the issue and fixed it right away!

-- Rick